# ontology-entity-matching from multi-keyword-query / subgraph extraction

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, ontology, string-matching

### Example

I have an ontology with many entities and relations. Let's look at the following example:

The user types "brad pitt angelina jolie" then the system should output the following subgraph

[image: example-of-subgraph]

### Question

How do I find out which of the tokens "brad", "pitt", "angelina", "jolie" should be taken together to match to the entities **Brad Pitt** and **Angelina Jolie**?

In this example the solution would be: Take "brad" and "pitt" together as "brad pitt" to match to the entity **Brad Pitt** and the second and the third token together as "angelina jolie" to match the entity **Angelina Jolie**.

### Difficulty

I don't know how many entities are contained in the query-string and entities may contain many tokens like **Karl Theodor zu Guttenberg**.

### Guess

I guess that there's probably a lot of research done in this field -- but I'm missing the entry point or the technical terms.

Comment: Entity Recognition and Natural Language Processing seem like they should play a role before ontologies enter the picture.

Comment: Entity Recognition is the perfect keyword I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Is there any special algorithms for keyword-style-queries, not containing natural-language but only names of entities?

Comment: None that I can think of, in those terms.